# How to build a multi instance systemd service configuration?

Tags: systemd

I am trying to configure systemd to be able to execute multiple instances of the same service but it seems that I am doing something wrong and the documentation resources seem not to be quite so clear.

Created `/lib/systemd/system/confluence@.service` file with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Confluence %i
After=postgresql.service nginx.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%i/bin/start-confluence.sh
ExecStartPre=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%i/bin/setenv.sh prestart

ExecStop=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%i/bin/stop-confluence.sh

TimeoutStopSec=5min
PIDFile=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%i/work/catalina.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So far, so good, the `systemctl enable confluence.test` reported success (and yes the /opt/atlassian/confluence-test/ "happens" to contain the what it needs.

Still, when I try to start the service using `systemctl start confluence` I get:

```
root@atlas:/lib/systemd/system# systemctl start confluence@test.service
Job for confluence@test.service failed. See "systemctl status confluence@test.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@atlas:/lib/systemd/system# systemctl status confluence@test.service
● confluence@test.service - Confluence test
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/confluence@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-10-09 13:25:28 BST; 7s ago
  Process: 16352 ExecStartPre=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%i/bin/setenv.sh prestart (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Oct 09 13:25:28 atlas systemd[1]: Starting Confluence test...
Oct 09 13:25:28 atlas systemd[1]: confluence@test.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Oct 09 13:25:28 atlas systemd[1]: Failed to start Confluence test.
Oct 09 13:25:28 atlas systemd[1]: Unit confluence@test.service entered failed state.
Oct 09 13:25:28 atlas systemd[1]: confluence@test.service failed.
```

Somehow it seems that systemd does not expand the "%i" which is supposed to be the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

I have been bouncing all around the Web looking for the pieces I need to create my own set of `systemd` unit, template and target files. This question was in the pile of search results. In this case, rather than finding help, I think I can give help.

I don't have Confluence, and won't install it to test, so I am mostly guessing for the first part.

I believe the problem is that the `%i` specifier is *escaped* and could be creating bad paths in the commands. If that is the whole problem, changing to the *unescaped* version, `%I`, would be the simplest solution. Your file `/lib/systemd/system/confluence@.service` would then become:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Confluence %I
After=postgresql.service nginx.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%I/bin/start-confluence.sh
ExecStartPre=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%I/bin/setenv.sh prestart

ExecStop=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%I/bin/stop-confluence.sh

TimeoutStopSec=5min
PIDFile=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%I/work/catalina.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If, on the other hand, the problem has a different root, such as specifiers not expanding in the commands, you can still accomplish the same results using a wrapper script. `systemd` is supposed to eliminate the need for them, but using older systems in newer processes often results in the theory not matching practice.

Create a shell script, perhaps in the directory that is the base for everything else anyway.

Create `/opt/atlassian/conflencectl` with this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Check that there is a command to execute
if ( ! test -n "$1" ) {
  exit 1
}

# Check that there is an instance name to use
if ( ! test -n "$2" ) {
  exit 1
}

# Make the directory name stub for this instance
InstanceDirName="confluence-$2"

# Execute the proper command, based on the command from the unit file
case $1 in
  Start)
    /opt/atlassian/$InstanceDirName/bin/start-confluence.sh;
    ;;
  StartPre )
    /opt/atlassian/$InstanceDirName/bin/setenv.sh prestart;
    ;;
  Stop )
    /opt/atlassian/$InstanceDirName/bin/stop-confluence.sh;
    ;;
  *)
    exit 1;
esac
```

Depending on what is, or is not, needed for the operations, you could add additional safety, sanity, or dependency checks, such as testing for the existence of the directory or needed config files.

Your `systemd` unit file then becomes:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Confluence %I
After=postgresql.service nginx.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/atlassian/conflencectl "Start" "%i"
ExecStartPre=/opt/atlassian/conflencectl "StartPre" "%i"

ExecStop=/opt/atlassian/conflencectl "Stop" "%i"

TimeoutStopSec=5min
PIDFile=/opt/atlassian/confluence-%I/work/catalina.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Even with this version I'm not too sure what will happen with the `PIDFile` declaration, nor how to compensate, if needed, using the wrapper script. The documentation I've scanned seems to imply that `systemd` is pretty good at knowing the PID anyway, and it may not be needed. Only testing will prove the final effects, however.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a separate start/stop script for each instance.

I would suggest `ExecStart=/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/start-confluence.sh`

This will start a new instance every-time it is called.

Same goes for `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStop`

Comment: Based on the feedback I received from a colleague, I think that's not really correct. He told me that only the first parameter of the commands does not support variable expansion, which means that using /bin/bash or /bin/sh should be an alternative for implementing this. Anyway, I will need more time until I will find a reliable way to spawn new instances.

Comment: I agree. But are you going to have separate script files for each instance? Instead, you can pass the instance name as an argument and handle it inside the script.

Comment: `ExecStart=/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/start-confluence.sh %i` would do.

Comment: Not for Atlassian products because is almost impossible to spawn them like this, needing different directories for each instance (also needed in order to be able to run different versions in parallel).